# Handling Jinja2 exceptions in efficient way

Tags: python, jinja2

I read many articles about handling all the jinja2 exceptions in one hand, but none of them handled the entire jinja2 exceptions. For example

```
except jinja2.TemplateSyntaxError as e:
  pass
```

It handles only particular error cases. How do I handle all exceptions in jinja2 efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

The following code handles all jinja2 exceptions because `TemplateError` is a base class of all exceptions.

```
except jinja2.TemplateError as e:
    pass
```